# How do describe items where one action was done one more time compared to another action

Tags: phrase-requests

I have items that can be installed and uninstalled. I have a list that contains all the items that were installed one more time than they were uninstalled.

My first guess to describe the list is: "The list contains items that were installed once more than uninstalled". To myself that sounds wrong. It sounds like a literal translation from german (I'm german) but I can't think of a way that sounds right.

How would you say this correctly?

EDIT: The phrase is a comment in source code. At first sight the code looks more complicated than it needs to be. The complete comment is:

> remove() (in contrast to removeAll()) only removes one instance of a component if the component is in the list multiple times. This results in a list that only contains components that were installed once more than uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, your original phrasing "The list contains items that were installed once more than uninstalled" sounds fine. Unless it's completely obvious, I would probably add something to explain why you're choosing to phrase it in that way, though, rather than just say "These items are currently installed".

Answer (score 0):

If one item is either installed (if installer more than uninstalled) or uninstalled (if uninstalled more than installed), I would say :

> The list contains items currently installed

And have a second list of items uninstalled described in the same way.

Do the user need to know more than that?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and makes assumptions that may or may not be true.

Comment: I didn't get why he need help to have a proper sentence if not for user content. I though user didn't need more infos, my bad on guessing